# Appending 4 divs at a time (from a list of divs) into a separate divs

Tags: jquery, append

I'm trying to append 4 divs at a time (from a list of divs) into a specific divs with class .movehere.

This is what I'm looking for:

```html
<section id="oldsection"></section>
<section id="newsection">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="movehere">
      <div class="moveme"></div>
      <div class="moveme"></div>
      <div class="moveme"></div>
      <div class="moveme"></div>
   </div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="movehere">
      <div class="moveme"></div>
      <div class="moveme"></div>
      <div class="moveme"></div>
   </div>
</section>
```

the original code is

```html
<section id="oldsection">
      <div class="moveme"></div>
      <div class="moveme"></div>
      <div class="moveme"></div>
      <div class="moveme"></div>
      <div class="moveme"></div>
      <div class="moveme"></div>
      <div class="moveme"></div></section>
<section id="newsection">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="movehere">
   </div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="movehere">
   </div>
</section>
```

I can move each of the .moveme divs using .each and .append

```html
   $('#oldsection .moveme').each(function () {
      #(".movehere").append($(this));        
   });
```

I'm not sure how to get the counting to work
Perhaps using a counting mechanism...?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply target the movehere elements, and move 4 at a time.  Once you've moved them all, the selector will find none to move.

```js
$('.movehere').each((_, destination) => {
  $('#oldsection .moveme').slice(0, 4).appendTo(destination);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="oldsection">
  <div class="moveme">1</div>
  <div class="moveme">2</div>
  <div class="moveme">3</div>
  <div class="moveme">4</div>
  <div class="moveme">5</div>
  <div class="moveme">6</div>
  <div class="moveme">7</div>
</section>
<section id="newsection">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="movehere">
  </div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="movehere">
  </div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="movehere">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I applied this code to a large one I was working on and it worked great :) I appreciate your help!